# How does one come up with the model of torque?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, torque, models

In school, we learn that $T = Fd$, where $T$ is the torque, $F$ is the force perpendicular to the moment arm, and $d$ is the length of the moment arm. If I was the first physicist to come up with this model for torque, what might my train of thought be? In other words, how does one come up with this model?

Comment: The rate of change of angular momentum is directly proportional to the net unbalanced torque acting on it for a rigid body. $$L = mvr$$ $$\tau = \frac{dL}{dt} = m(v\frac{dr}{dt} + r\frac{dv}{dt}) = mr\frac{dv}{dt} = mra = r ma = rF$$

Comment: Newton's laws of motion...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How was the torque-force relationship discovered](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/290576/)

Answer (score 2):

The way you worded the question sounds to me like you're asking more for an intuitive understanding of why someone thought *Fd* would be a useful enough quantity to give it its own name, why it's taught to kids as a sort of fundamental equation rather than just another step in a derivation, and also where it fits into the big picture.

If that's the case, however, I can't tell you what the actual line of thinking really was, but I can at least offer you one view of why we consider it to be an important/fundamental quantity.

You can think of torque as being the rotational analog of linear force. We observe some simple relationships such as:
$$\omega_{\text{avg}}=\frac{v_{\text{tangential}}}{r}$$
$$\alpha_{\text{avg}}=\frac{a_{\text{tangential}}}{r}$$
and one might wonder, if we simply multiply the $a_{\text{tangential}}$ by *m*, will the result give us something akin to rotational force?

Well it turns out if you do you get:

$m\alpha_{\text{avg}}=\frac{ma}{r}$

Of course the *ma* quantity is our familiar linear force, however if you multiply both sides by $r^{2}$ you will find "moment of inertia" on the left:

$(mr^{2})\alpha_{\text{avg}}=\frac{F}{r}(r^{2})=Fr$

therefore it is reasonable to think of $(mr^{2})\alpha$ as some sort of "angular force" which we've named "torque" usually given the symbol $\tau$, and to think of $mr^{2}$ almost as a sort of "angular mass" which we have given the name "Moment of Inertia" with the symbol *I*.