# Can Newton's second law for rotation be derived from Newton's second law for translation?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics

I am referring to the [Newton's second law for rotation](http://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/pasp/Newton_s_Second_Law_Rotations.html):

$\vec{\tau}=I \vec{\alpha}$

Which obviously is the analogue for Newton's second law for translation

$\vec{F}=M \vec{a}$

I wonder whether the rotation law can be derived from transnational one? If yes, how can we do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/244655/50583

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mathematically yes (as shown below), but it is always good to understand Force equations as conservation of linear momentum or angular momentum.

Taking cross-product on either side of linear force balance with $\vec{r}$, we get
\begin{equation}
\vec{F}\times \vec{r} = [M\vec{a}]\times \vec{r}
\end{equation}

we know that, 
\begin{equation}
\vec{F}\times \vec{r} = \vec{\tau}; \ \vec{a}= r\vec{\alpha};  \ Mr^2 = I; 
\end{equation}

Therefore,
\begin{equation}
\vec{F}\times \vec{r} = \vec{\tau} = [Mr^2\vec{\alpha}] = I\vec{\alpha}
\end{equation}